# Rating is temporarily unavailable, please try again later. Nop Commerce 4.2 fedex plugin issue

Tags: nopcommerce, fedex, nopcommerce-4.2

I have recently started working on nop commerce 4.2 version.
I have added FedEx plugin for the shipping. refer the following link

https://www.nopcommerce.com/shipping-plugin-for-fedex

while calling the rate service I am getting **"Rating is temporarily unavailable, please try again later."** error

My App Rate service  URL is **https://wsbeta.fedex.com:443/web-services/rate**

Please help me with a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to figure out if the response comes from FedEx or generated by the plugin. You need to intercept the communications between the plugin and FedEx. One of the recording proxies should help (f.ex. Fiddler).

Then review is request and response trying to figure out who's wrong. Wrong credentials? Request data? Or maybe the FexEx service is truly down and nobody mans it due to the COVID.